# HRA exemption by wife

Tags: income-tax, india, international, house-rent-allowance

I and my wife both are Salary Earners and getting HRA (House Rent Allowance). Now I am employed at DUBAI in a Foreign Company and living there.

I have two houses in India.
One house is rented and in other house my family (Wife) is living.
I am living out of Country due to my employment.

Can I give my house to my wife on Rent and can my wife claim HRA exemption?

For Income in India such as Rent and Interest on Deposits in Bank I will be filing Income Tax Return as per Income Tax Act.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I give my house to my wife on Rent and can my wife claim HRA exemption?

No you cannot give your house on rent to your spouse, and your wife cannot claim the HRA exemption.